# Undeclared Identifier (Bogus) Error at Delphi

Tags: delphi

At `Delphi -> Help -> Table Of Content -> Code Example -> Delphi -> ActnMgrBar`, There is tutorial regd Action Manager Component. Anyone can retrieve this tutorial at Help and check out.

> Description : This application requires a TPopupActionBar component already on the form. The application creates an action manager component and assigns an image list to some of its properties. Then, the popup action bar is customized and assigned to the form's PopupMenu property. Right click the form to show the popup menu.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Images: TImageList;
  Image: TBitmap;
  ActionManager: TActionManager;  
  Option1, Option2: TMenuItem;
begin
  // display an information message
  ShowMessage('Right click the form to display the customized popup menu');
  // create an image list
  Images := TImageList.Create(self);
  Images.Height := 32;
  Images.Width := 32;
  try
    Image := TBitmap.Create;
    Image.Height := 32;
    Image.Width := 32;
    Image.Canvas.Font.Name := 'Times New Roman';
    Image.Canvas.Font.Size := 22;
    Image.Canvas.TextOut((Image.Width - Image.Canvas.TextWidth('1')) div 2, 0, '1');
    Images.Add(Image, nil);
  finally
    Image.Free;
  end;
  // create an action manager and assign the image list to some of its properties
  ActionManager := TActionManager.Create(self);  
  ActionManager.DisabledImages := Images;  
  ActionManager.LargeDisabledImages  := Images;  
  ActionManager.LargeImages := Images;
  // add some items to the popup menu associated with the popup action bar
  Option1:= TMenuItem.Create(self);
  Option1.Caption := 'New';
  PopupActionBar1.Items.Add(Option1);
  Option2:= TMenuItem.Create(self);
  Option2.Caption := 'Save';
  PopupActionBar1.Items.Add(Option2);
  // let the popup action bar be the form's popup menu
  Form1.PopupMenu := PopupActionBar1;
end;
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Undeclared Identifier : TActionManager
```

This type of Undeclared Identifier error I get quiet often at my Delphi (Earlier I got same type of error with `TAniIndicator`) where component is declared at source.  In above case, if I manually put `TActionManager` on form then code works.  Someone told me there must be error with installation or configuration of Delphi on my HP PC.

Comment: Add `ActnMan` to [`the uses clause`](http://i.imgur.com/0DZTDK0.png).

Comment: I am using Embarcadero® Delphi® XE4 version....

Comment: What's bogus is the formatting. This is unreadable. Please fix it.

Comment: So then you have [`Vcl.ActnMan`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Vcl.ActnMan) with a full namespace.

Comment: @Remy I think there was three of us editing the question code layout at the same time ;-)

Comment: Not a "bogus" error at all. If you don't have the proper unit in the uses clause that defines a `TActionManager`, the `TActionManager` type doesn't exist, making it an "undeclared identifier".

Comment: I'm impressed by how an example in official documentation can be this pointless. Create a component and assign an imagelist to some of its properties, and do not even use the component or images anywhere.

Answer (score 6):

When you drop a `TActionManager` onto a Form at design-time, the IDE automatically inserts the necessary `ActnMan` unit reference into the Form unit's `uses` clause.  The example obviously does not have that reference, hense the error.  So simply add the `ActnMan` unit to your `uses` clause manually.

Comment: And just to be completely clear, whoever told you "there must be error with installation or configuration of Delphi on my HP PC" is **completely wrong**. It's simply that when you use components manually (instead of letting the IDE manage them) you need to do all the steps that the IDE does.